# Проход по for i in 0..vector.len() и 'index out of bounds'

Tags: rust

Делаю задачу для тренировки, в последнем `for` выскакивает ошибка о выходе за границы вектора :

> thread '<main>' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 22 but the index is 22', ../src/libcollections/vec.rs:1106*

Не могу понять, почему так происходит, в цикле `for` не проверяется результат `len()` при каждом новом проходе цикла?

```
fn main(){
    let e = 0.005;
    let n = 30;
    let mut vector: Vec<f32>;
    vector = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..n {
        let result:f32 = 1./(i as f32 + 1.).powf(2.0);
        vector.push( result );
    }
    for i in 0..vector.len(){
        println!("len:{:?}", vector.len());
        if vector[i] < e {
            println!("{:?}", vector[i]);
            vector.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Я переделал под `while` и всё работает, но заводить счётчик до цикла как-то не красиво, да и `i+=1;` тоже, можно ли как-то это оформить посимпотичнее? Вот что получилось вместо последнего `for`

```
let mut i=0;
while( i < vector.len() ){
    if vector[i] < e {
        println!("{:?}", vector[i]);
        vector.remove(i);
    }
    i+=1;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В добавление советую внимательно прочитать документацию по [Vec](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) и [Iterator](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html). Практически всегда, когда хочется сделать `for i in 0..vec.len()` в расте нужно использовать итерирование по вектору напрямую или какой-то метод самого вектора или итератора от него. В частности в данном случае гораздо лучше использовать [Vec::retain()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain), а для построения [Iterator::collect()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) и [Iterator::map()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map):

```
let mut vector = (0..n).map(|i| 1./(i as f32 + 1.).powf(2.0)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
vector.retain(|item| item >= e);
```

Плюс ещё в том, что если использовать библиотечные методы и итераторы, то не будет сгенерирован код для проверки выхода индекса за границы массива (bounds check), как при использовании операции индексирования `[]`.

Comment: не хотелось бы создавать новую тему, но как задать шаг в такой конструкции (0..n) ? Я в доке не нашёл...

Comment: Есть [Range::step_by()](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/ops/struct.Range.html#method.step_by), но он пока не стабилен, так что доступен только в nightly. Если хотите использовать stable, то можно нагородить конструкцию из filter: `(0..n).filter(|&i| i % step == 0)`, или, в случае вектора: `vec.into_iter().enumerate().filter(|&(i, _)| i % step == 0)`. В последнем случае с enumerate будет итератор по кортежам из индекса и элемента.

Comment: Ещё момент, `into_iter()` поглощает вектор и позволяет итераторировать по значению. Если вектор ещё будет нужен, то надо использовать `iter()` или `iter_mut()`, которые только заимствуют вектор, но итераторы будут по ссылке на элементы.

Comment: спасибо... да уж простой и лаконичный синтаксис(с)....

Comment: Дело привычки. Ну и потом, здесь это выглядит не очень хорошо в одну строчку. Если хорошо отформатировать, то выглядит даже симпатично.

Answer (score 5):

С помощью выражения `0..vector.len()` вы получаете итератор, который возвращает числа от 0 до *исходной длины* вектора. Однако внутри цикла вы удаляете элементы, поэтому индекс выходит за границы.

Это не сишный `for`, здесь итератор создаётся один раз в самом начале, и его верхяя граница не обновляется вместе с изменением размера вектора. Если вы хотите менять длину вектора во время итерирования по нему, вам нужно использовать `while`, потому что в этом случае верхяя граница будет проверяться каждый раз.

К слову, при таком способе удаления инкрементировать переменную цикла следует, только если элемент не был удалён, иначе вы пропустите идущие подряд элементы, которые подлежат удалению.